# PHP: Two buttons will proceed to a different page

Tags: php, button

I have two buttons in one form called it main.php....The buttons are "View" and "Save".. So the "View" button will go to the view.php and then the "save" button will go to the save.php page. My problem is I have a codes for script, when I click the "View" its working but when I click the "Save" button its also redirect to the view.php not in the save.php.

Here's my Codes:

```
<head>
function changeFrm(){
    document.getElementById("view").src="view.php";
    document.getElementById("save").src="save.php";
}
</head>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="view" value="View Building/s" onClick="changeFrm();">    
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onClick="changeFrm();">
</form>
```

I also tried the

```
<input type="submit" name="view" value="View Building/s" onClick="parent.changeFrm();"> 
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onClick="parent.changeFrm();">
```

but still the same...

Here's the code for save:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($bldg);$i++)
                {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO tbldata(fldNetname,fldBldgName,fldPlaylist,fldDuration,fldFrom,fldTo) VALUES ('".$network."','".$bldg[$i]."','".$AdName."','".$duration."','".$from."','".$to."')";
                    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
                }
                echo "save";
```

For View Page. It will just load again the view.php

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the form tags and view and save elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
    <input type="button" value="button1" onClick="this.form.action='your_first_action_url'; this.form.submit()">
    <input type="button" value="button2" onClick="this.form.action='your_second_action_url';this.form.submit()">
```

and with `<form action="">`

Comment: @user2471815...hey...thanks for the answer...and it works!..thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you came about this code, but it's definitely not doing what you think it's supposed to be doing.

1. Your JavaScript code isn't going to change anything because there are no elements with `id` values of `view` or `save`.
2. There is no meaningful `src` attribute for `input` elements, so even if it was finding those elements those wouldn't make a difference.

When you click a `submit` button, the form posts to the `action` attribute in the `form` tag which contains that button.  If there's no explicit `action` on the `form` then I imagine it will submit to the currently loaded URL (the current page).

Instead of having two `submit` buttons, you should probably have one "default" `submit` which posts to whichever is the default page (and have that page be the `action` in the `form` element) and then one regular button which you use to "submit" to another page via JavaScript.  Something like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="view" id="viewButton" value="View Building/s" /> 
<input type="button" name="save" id="saveButton" value="Save" />
```

Then for your JavaScript, something like this:

```
document.getElementById('saveButton').onclick = function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('theIDOfYourForm');
    form.action = 'save.php';
    form.submit();
}
```

This is untested, so it might need some tweaking with the submit action on the `form`.  But basically the idea is that the second button isn't technically a `submit` so it doesn't cause the form to post by default.  Instead, you add a click event handler to it in JavaScript which changes the `action` of the form and submits it manually.

Also of note here is the way I've structured the JavaScript.  Instead of calling a JavaScript function in-line from the HTML code, I left the HTML clean and instead "bind" to the click event of the button once when the page loads.  This is a more "unobstrusive" way to structure JavaScript, which allows you to modify the JavaScript and the HTML independently of each other more easily.